# yum install error trying to install from epel8 not 7

Tags: centos, yum

I have a centos 7 server and i am trying to install a certain package but i am getting error package and the package names are all .el8 but i dont understand why this is the case? 
There is no epel8 in my repo list:

```
repo id                                                    repo name                                                                                       status
base/7/x86_64                                              CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                 10,097
epel/x86_64                                                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                  13,455
extras/7/x86_64                                            CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                  305
salt-latest/x86_64                                         SaltStack Latest Release Channel for RHEL/Centos 7                                                 107
salt-py3-2019.2/x86_64                                     SaltStack 2019.2 Release Channel for Python 3 RHEL/Centos 7                                         84
saltstack/x86_64                                           SaltStack latest Release Channel for RHEL/CentOS 7                                                 107
updates/7/x86_64                                           CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                 711
repolist: 24,866
```

Can i force epel7?

Output for the errors

```
Error: Package: python3-m2crypto-0.33.0-1.el8.x86_64 (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: salt-2019.2.2-1.el8.noarch (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: python3-markupsafe
Error: Package: python3-m2crypto-0.33.0-1.el8.x86_64 (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: python3-m2crypto-0.33.0-1.el8.x86_64 (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: zeromq-4.3.1-4.el8.x86_64 (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: salt-2019.2.2-1.el8.noarch (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: python3-pyyaml
Error: Package: python3-m2crypto-0.33.0-1.el8.x86_64 (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: salt-2019.2.2-1.el8.noarch (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: python3-requests
Error: Package: zeromq-4.3.1-4.el8.x86_64 (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: zeromq-4.3.1-4.el8.x86_64 (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: salt-2019.2.2-1.el8.noarch (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: python3-six
Error: Package: salt-2019.2.2-1.el8.noarch (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: python3-jinja2
Error: Package: salt-master-2019.2.2-1.el8.noarch (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: python3-systemd
Error: Package: python3-m2crypto-0.33.0-1.el8.x86_64 (salt-py3-2019.2)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
```

Comment: The first issue I see is that you have three separate SaltStack repositories installed, pare that down to just the one you need.  If you can show the output of `rpm -qf $(grep -H 'baseurl\|mirror' $(grep -HRl salt /etc/yum.repos.d/) | tee /dev/stderr | awk -F: '{print $1}')`, we may be able to determine where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the three salt-stack repo's which as mentioned caused the issue. Install ran fine after that.
in the folder /etc/yum.repos.d/
Removed the three salt repos
Installed a single repo relating to salt.
ran the install script again and it no longer errors on the packages.

Comment: No looks like an answer